# Is a less probabilistic quantum entanglement possible

Tags: quantum-entanglement

I am trying to understand the core issues of quantum entanglement. There is a video by Veritasium: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuvK-od647c, which is pretty well explained, however it is still heavily probabilistic. I have imagined a simpler "magical objects" achieving similar properties but being a bit easier to comprehend. I was curious whether something like that could be theoretically created with quantum physics, or whether it can be presented only as a tool for better understanding.

Imagine two ("entangled") boxes, both with three buttons 'A', 'B', 'C'. When a button is pressed on one of them, the box responds with a random bit of information (50% ⇾ '0', 50% ⇾ '1'), and it cannot be used anymore. If you press the same button on both boxes, you are guaranteed (or almost guaranteed) to get the same value. If you press different buttons, you are guaranteed (or almost guaranteed) to get the opposite values.

Could such boxes be modeled using quantum physics?